# putting the xsl condition in a better way

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Please advise is there any better way to express this below xsl condition or this below one is correct.. we are using xslt 1.0

```
<xsl:if test="$abcPeriod_first=gfd_Rate">
    <xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="'BBB'" />
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? It seems to me that regardless of the condition, you end up with `BBB`.

Comment: It's only wrong if you get output that you don't want. So can you edit your question to show what you want it to output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an `if...else` then I believe your current condition is not sufficient. You could use the following:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$abcPeriod_first=gfd_Rate">
    <xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="'BBB'" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```